# Emacs: make longlines-mode default for the compilation buffer?

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to make longlines mode the default for just the *compilation* buffer?

Comment: Just commenting to note that longlines mode will be deprecated in favour of visual-line-mode in the upcoming Emacs 24.4 release.  (visual-line-mode was added in version 23.1.)

Comment: Dandy! Any word on plans to make visual-line-mode work properly?

Answer (score 2):

There sure is; you add to the compilation-mode-hook, which is called any time you enter compilation mode, a function which sets longlines-mode. Add the following to your `~/.emacs`, or some other such suitable place:

```
  (defun compilation-mode-longlines-hook ()
    "Set longlines-mode when entering compilation mode."
    (longlines-mode t))

  (add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook 'compilation-mode-longlines-hook)
```