# Emacs compilation-mode to always use visual-line-mode

Tags: emacs

I'm attempting to have emacs compilation-mode always use visual-line-mode. The code I'm using is:

```
(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook (visual-line-mode))
```

I've tried various other permutations. Such as the version in:

- [Emacs: make longlines-mode default for the compilation buffer?](https://superuser.com/questions/581125/emacs-make-longlines-mode-default-for-the-compilation-buffer)

Or globally enabling visual-line-mode

```
(setq-default global-visual-line-mode t)
```

Yet emacs insists on truncating lines. I've confirmed the hook is executing. Is there a known resolution for this?

### Update 0

The primary issue is a Lisp newbie problem: The function `visual-line-mode` was not quoted. This results in an immediate evaluation and not evaluation when the hook is fired.

This did not resolve the issue: compilation mode still does not wrap lines. I've confirmed the hook is being executed at the expected time by placing a undefined identifier instead of `t`. Emacs complains, as expected, of the undefined identifier when compilation mode is entered.

Is there a way to trace execution of `compile`? Using `(trace-function 'compile)` produces:

```
======================================================================
1 -> compile: command="make" comint=nil
1 <- compile: #<buffer *compilation*>
```

and nothing more.

### Update 1

**Solved!**

As well as incorrect quoting, the issue was with another part of my emacs config:

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
      (function
        (lambda ()
            (fci-mode)
            (turn-on-auto-fill)
        )
      )
)
```

which, effectively, undid the `visual-line-mode` setting!

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by lawlist is the correct one, however, there is also a compilation minor mode that is used by some major modes (CIDER's stacktrace-mode, for example).  Thus, I have the following:

```
(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook
          (lambda () (visual-line-mode 1)))

(add-hook 'compilation-minor-mode-hook
          (lambda () (visual-line-mode 1)))
```

I mention this because the minor code also presents as "Compilation" on the status bar, and it took me a little while to figure out that it was the minor, and not the major mode.

(I'd have preferred to simply comment on lawlist's answer, but I don't currently have enough rep to do so.)